# Flexpaper overlapping html elements

Tags: flash, flexpaper

I know that I have to set the `wmode` property, but where do I set the property in flex paper.

Following is the code to embed Flexpaper into the HTML document.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
                    var doc                 = '<?php print $doc; ?>';
                    var numPages            = <?php echo getTotalPages($pdfFilePath . $doc) ?>;
                    var swfFileUrl          = escape('{services/view.php?doc='+doc+'&page=[*,0],'+numPages+'}');
                    var searchServiceUrl    = escape('services/containstext.php?doc='+doc+'&page=[page]&searchterm=[searchterm]');

                    var fp = new FlexPaperViewer(   
                             'FlexPaperViewer',
                             'viewerPlaceHolder', { config : {
                             SwfFile : swfFileUrl, 
                             Scale : 1, 
                             ZoomTransition : 'easeOut',
                             ZoomTime : 0.5,
                             ZoomInterval : 0.2,
                             FitPageOnLoad : false,
                             FitWidthOnLoad : false,
                             FullScreenAsMaxWindow : false,
                             ProgressiveLoading : false,
                             MinZoomSize : 0.2,
                             MaxZoomSize : 5,
                             SearchMatchAll : true,
                             SearchServiceUrl : searchServiceUrl,
                             InitViewMode : 'Portrait',
                             BitmapBasedRendering : false,

                             ViewModeToolsVisible : true,
                             ZoomToolsVisible : true,
                             NavToolsVisible : true,
                             CursorToolsVisible : true,
                             SearchToolsVisible : true,

                             localeChain: 'en_US'
                             }});           
                </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a way to do this by passing a param to the FlexPaperViewer constructor but you may be able to solve it in flexpaper_flash.js. Near line 19 and try adding the `wmode` param there:

```
window.FlexPaperViewer = window.$f = function() {
    var config = arguments[2].config;

    window.FlexPaperViewer_Instance = flashembed(arguments[1], {
        //add wmode here
        wmode: "transparent",
        src: arguments[0]+".swf",
        version: [10, 0],
        expressInstall: "js/expressinstall.swf"
    },{
        ...
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A better idea is to just add the following to your flexpaper config:

Like this:

```
var fp = new FlexPaperViewer(
                            '<%:FlexPaperViewer %>',
                            'documentViewer', { config: {

                                    SwfFile: '<%:SwfFile%>.swf',
                                    IMGFiles: '<%:SwfFile%>_{page}.png',
                                    JSONFile: '/GetJson.ashx?q=<%=SwfFile%>.json',

                                    ...lots of other irrelevant params...
                                    WMode : 'transparent',

                                    localeChain: 'en_US'
                                }
                            });
```

Flexpaper will pick-up the WMode and set it on Flash object (I am using flexpaper 1.5 (may 2012))

Answer (score 0):

wmode is actually a configuration parameter you set on your SWF embed code in HTML. To answer more specifically you'd need to show how you're embedding the code, and the wmode value FlexPaper requires. However, here are a few ways to set it based on popular embedding methods.

Add this next to the existing param tags if you're using the HTML style of embedding SWF movies.

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

Alternatively if you're using SWFObject to embed your SWF you can set the wmode like so:

```
var flashvars = {},
params = {wmode:"transparent"},
attributes = {};

swfobject.embedSWF("/swf/yourSWF.swf", "anim", "300", "200", "9.0.0", "/swf/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
```

For more information see the Adobe documentation on the [wmode parameter](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html#main_Using_Window_Mode__wmode__values_).